# Slice of Radio and Ithobox

Tags: python, serial

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Ciseco Slice of Radio and I'd like to control my Ithobox [LINK](http://www.ithodaalderop.nl/producten/ventilatie-hele-huis/mechanische-ventilatie/cve-eco-rft)

It has an 868 Mhz RF transmitter/receiver and I also have the optional RF remote control unit which I'll be placing in my bathroom. I would like to monitor the current setting of the unit and be able to change it.

The remote control can be linked to this Ithobox by starting the Ithobox up a certain way and then pressing a few buttons on the remote. I would like to copy this information the remote control sends out so I can also link the Raspberry in the same way.

So, I need the Raspberry to listen to all RF signals received and log that into a text file so I can try and send that out to the Ithobox.

I'm basically trying to have the Raspberry copy all RF signals the official remote control sends out..

Where do I start? I have some experience programming in Python but have never done anything related to serial ports so I don't know where to start..

Thanks ahead!

Comment: I have ordered it too. Did you had success using slide of radio? Did you use minicom as I saw on a tutorial online?

Comment: To do this successfully, you need a signal analyser because there are many ways to issue RF signals. Most likely, the remote will issue a timing-related set of signals and you need to work out what those are so that you can replay them. The easiest way is with an oscilloscope. If you don't have one, you may be able to make your own using the Pi! Google will point the way.